# Prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} = \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\log 2}{3}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

> Prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} = \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\log 2}{3}$$

I tried to look at $$ f_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1} x^n $$

And maybe taking it's derivative but it didn't work out well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take $x^{3n+1}$ instead of $x^n$.

Comment: Oh I actually thought about trying it but somehow gave up on that

Comment: Change the $ x^n $ into $ x^{3n} $. Then $ f (x) $ is $\frac{1}{x}$ times the integral from $0$ to $ x$ of what series?

Comment: I talk to derivatives too sometimes, it's our secret. Also think about the natural log...

Comment: @GPerez, You should try to have a conversation with an imporer integral then!

Comment: I've tried but they're just so uncouth. Now that you've edited though I sound like a weird guy

Comment: Oh and disregard the part in my first comment that actually addresses the question, I thought you could approach the problem with the $\log$ series but it seems a different solution has been shown.

Comment: I have answered an exactly similar problem on [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=296&t=616914) & I give a complete answer, you may visit the link I give.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀, could you explain the second equality in your answer? (the change from summation to the integral with $e$)

Comment: @AlonAlon Do you mean interchanging the integral & summation sign? It can be justified by Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\int_0^1t^{3n}dt=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^N(-t^3)^ndt=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{1-(-t^3)^{N+1}}{1+t^3}dt$$

Now you need to prove two things:

- $$\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1+t^3}=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}+\frac{\log 2}{3}$$
- $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{(-t^3)^{N+1}}{1+t^3}dt=0$$

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the second equality please?

Comment: Which equality do you mean? Interchanging $\sum$ and $\int$? It's possible with finite sum.

Comment: @AlonAlon Since $0<t<1$, then as $N\to\infty$ the integrand goes to $0$

Comment: You're welcome @AlonAlon

Comment: Is it legal: $\lim_{N\to\infty} \int_0^1 (-t^3)^{N+1} = \int_0^1 0 = 0$? (Meaning, talking the limit before evaluating the integral)

Comment: To prove the second point use that
$$\left|\int_0^1\frac{(-t^3)^{N+1}}{1+t^3}dt\right|\le\int_0^1 t^{3N+3}dt=\frac1{3N+4}$$
and then squeeze.

Comment: Thanks, Why doing it my way is wrong by the way?

Comment: We can't interchange in general $\lim$ and $\int$ without theorems: Dominated convergence theorem, limit monotone theorem, convergence uniform theorem,... Or prove the result *by hand* as I did.

Comment: This is a very nice approach especially I like the second part where the remainder is shown as tending to $0$. This is the way such elementary problems should be be done (i.e. without any appeal to uniform convergence, dominated convergence etc). +1

Comment: But Fubini and Tonelli's theorems justifies it for all sums/integrals less than infinity. These are less than infinity because they converge. We can directly apply that.

Answer (score 5):

For a geometric series.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(x^n) = \frac{1}{1+x}$$

Substitute $x \rightarrow x^3$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (x^{3n}) = \frac{1}{1+x^3}$$

Integrate the sides.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{3n + 1}}{3n + 1} = \int \frac{dx}{1+x^3}$$

The hard part is the integration. Then let $x=1$